# what's the preferred way to store sensitive settings in web apps?

Tags: security, deployment, cloud, production-environment

I know that a good way to store data like db passwords, etc. is via environment variables, but setting environment variables manually for every server instance created is time consuming.

I'm planning to deploy my project to the cloud (using aws ebs or heroku). 
where should I store my db password?

I think the .ebextensions file isn't a good option because it's tracked in vcs

Comment: https://12factor.net/config

Answer (score 2):

Don't ever store secrets in source control. A common practice is to either put them in a secure file or in something like https://www.vaultproject.io/ then inject them (programmatically via a script or some other deployment/configuration tool) into the environment when you bring up your VM (or container or whatever).

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to create a properties file which can be stored in the resources folder of your application and the code can access the resources.  do not need environment variable.  One property file can contain all db's userid and passwords.  Deploy job based on url mapping in the properties file.  For example, look at a spring hibernate example project which uses a property file.  Or look at ant deploy scripts.  Hope it helps.